# Tizen Native Application: Sample App with multiple text elements

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I am completely new to Tizen development. And I need to develop an Tizen wearable native application which shows 3 text views(1. for current step count, 2. speed, 3. for distance) as soon as I get values from the sensors I need to assign these values to text views. Currently I am able to get values from sensors using:

```
function onchangedCB(pedometerdata) {
     tizen.humanactivitymonitor.getHumanActivityData("PEDOMETER", onsuccessCB, onerrorCB);
} 

tizen.humanactivitymonitor.start("PEDOMETER", onchangedCB);
```

But stuck at UI part. I tried finding samples from Tizen but couldn't find it. Also I tried reading their documentation but Not able to design simple UI.

Comment: What kind of Multiple Text Elements ?

Comment: Please add a sketch image for understanding

Answer (score 0):

Take a Tizen TAU Basic project from Tizen Studio template. And use these code

**// index.html**

```
<div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
        <header class="ui-header">
            <h2 class="ui-title">TAU Basic</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="ui-content content-padding">
            <div>
                <span id="step"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="speed"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span id="distance"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

// **main.js**

```
 document.getElementById("step").innerHTML = "Step Count is 1100 ";
 document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = "Speed is 98 KM/h ";
 document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = "Distance covered 6.1 KM";
```

[image: Tizen Multiple text element]

Comment: Thanks Iqbal for your answer. Sorry I forgot to mention I need to develop Native application (C/ C++). Can you update your answer for native app?

Comment: yes, As I was not able to design UI when trying to use Native application so tried developing web application. and used web apis for getting data.

Comment: What have you tried in native part ? please post these and update the answer